# Excel formula for enter today date in A1 if B1 has a text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Could you help me please to find out an excel formula to enter today date in A1 if B1 has a specific word?

Comment: `=IF(A1="Specific Text",TODAY(),"")` would do this but it will update as soon as you open it.

Comment: Hey shrivallabha, thank you for your support. Actually this is my problem with the code that you wrote. Is there any way to ignore the updating?

Comment: Slight mod to @shrivallabha.redij 's comment: =IF(B1="Specific Text", TODAY(), ""). If you don't want the date to be updated every time you open the workbook, I'd say you can go to any other cell and use =TODAY() then copy this cell, paste as text, then replace `TODAY()` in the formula with this date value.

Comment: "Is there any way to ignore the updating? " >> with excel formula only, no. Need to learn and do it using vba, yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ♣Solved!♣

2 proposed solns/alternatives:

---

### (1) Excel function

Enter in cell A1:

=if("B1" = "whatever", today(),"")

To ignore updating, will need VB code most likely, or simply put Automatic Calc. off (tools, options, forumulas -> manual + untick 'recalc before saving') i.e.:

[image: Turn off automatic calc. to avoid auto-updates]

---

### (2) VB

VB code (open excel, press alt + f11 to open VB, select relevant sheet from within the 'Microsoft Excel Objects' dropdown list for workbook in question - you'll find this in the 'Project Explorer' window pane of VB, e.g. in my case, it's 'Sheet14 (Sheet1)" per screenshot below..):

[image: VB code]

Enter following code after selecting "Worksheet" and "Change" from drop-down lists in the main code section that opens up after you double click (in my case): "Sheet14 (Sheet1)", per above:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("b1").Value = "whatever" Then
        Range("a1").Value = Date
    End If
Else
    'do Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

(note: some trigger is required - above code assumes this will be cell B1 changing to "whatever" specific text).

---

References:
(adapted this for 'change' as opposed to 'selectionchange':)
[using intersect with 'selectionchange' or equivalent/similar](http://selection%20change:%20https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/worksheet-selectionchange.552778/)
date function:
[Date function: VB](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/date_vba.php)

---

**Pros/Cons (VB soln):**

Pro: Not effected by calculation updates or change in date clock events

Con: Requires VB

Con: More code required to remove content of cell A1 if B1 updated...

Pro: Auto-updates whenever cell changes

---

**VB test results**

[image: Test result - VB]

Comment: Thank you James, I appreciate your support 

Comment: Anytime friend. (consider upvoting - works better than rose is that the emoji pic you used? lol:)#

Comment: I knew that, I already gave u upvote, but i’m new on stackoverflow. So, i need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote. So, instead of that i gave u a rose 

Comment: np mate - appreciate it! :)